# Set Color to the drawableTop image inside a TextView in android

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-drawable

I have a textView with drawableTop, but the image is in black color and i would like to change the color to white.Is there a way to do it without creating seperate imageView and TextView.

Below is the xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_room"
    android:text="More"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Tint [android:drawableTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTint) to change color. Exmp :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:drawableTint="#fff"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_room"
    android:text="More"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have added android:drawableTint="@color/white" and my colors.xml has <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>.I still find the image is black.I also get a warning that android:drawableTint  is only used in API Level 23 and above. My projects min is 15. Am i missing something?

Comment: @RK1414 You would not normally use tint on a black Bitmap to color it. The original Bitmap file should be white. Then you can color it using tint. This is because tinting will normally multiply each pixel with the color you specify, and this works well with a white image. (From API 21 you can change the tinting mode to make this work with other images too.)

Comment: android:drawableTint is used only in API level 23 and higher, do you have any idea how to tint the drawable on API level <  23 in the XML?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 -** `@drawable/ic_add_room` if this is xml file then go to ic_add_room.xml inside drawable folder.

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24.0"
            android:viewportHeight="24.0">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M13,7h-2v4L7,11v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4L13,7zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
    </vector>
```

modify fillColor as your requirement...

> Example-

```
android:fillColor="#FFE25959"
```

**Solution 2 -** for change color dynamic

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GREEN);
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```