# How to set color of a TextView's Drawable in XML - for Android API 15?

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-color

My app is using `minSdkVersion 15` and I would like to set the color of a TextView's drawable using XML.

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35745819/1617737) to a similar question, but it requires API 23.

I'm currently changing the drawable color programmatically, but I would rather do it in XML - if it's possible to do what with API 15?

Comment: Are you using the support libraries/androidx? `AppCompatTextView` has its own `drawableTint` attribute that'll work (should work, anyway) on all supported versions. It'll be in your app's namespace, though, not the system namespace. That is, you'd use the `app` prefix, for example, instead of `android`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to my root element and replaced my `<TextView... />` with `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView... />`, then added the attribute `app:drawableTint="@color/red"`. But when I try to compile, I get this error: **error: attribute drawableTint (aka org.example.myapp:drawableTint) not found.** (NB - In my app's build.gradle, I am using `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`.) Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, guess it wasn't added until androidx, then. And, now that I look again, it's not listed in [the public resources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/res-public/values/public_attrs.xml), which is really odd. It's implemented, just not publicly exposed, for some reason: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml#906. Never mind about that, then, I s'pose. You could roll your own custom `TextView` to do it. It basically just sets a `ColorFilter` on the drawables.

Comment: Would you recommend using a custom `TextView` rather than migrating to androidx? If so, could you post an answer/example of how to do it with `ColorFilter`?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that migrating would help, as it seems that attribute isn't public, for whatever reason. I'm not certain of that, though, 'cause I was just going by the online source, and I've not yet checked it in a project. It'd be relatively easy to put together a simple custom subclass that'll do basically the same thing, but the fact that that attribute is hidden makes me wonder if there are some pesky edge cases in older versions that I'm not aware of. I'm not going to be able to test anything in the near future, but I'll let you know if/when I get to it.